# SQL SERVER Storage of TinyInt

Tags: sql-server-2008

In SQL Server, why is a tinyint stored with 9B in the row. For some reason there seems to be an additional one byte at the end of the NULL bitmap mask.

```
    USE tempdb ;
    GO

    CREATE TABLE tbl
    (
        i TINYINT NOT NULL
    ) ;
    GO

    INSERT INTO tbl (i)
        VALUES (1) ;
    GO

    DBCC IND ('tempdb','tbl',-1) ;
    GO

    DBCC TRACEON (3604) ; -- Page dump will go the console
    GO

    DBCC PAGE ('tempdb',1,168,3) ;
    GO
```

Results (I reversed the bytes due to DBCC PAGE's showing the least significant byte first):

```
Record Size = 9B
10000500 01010000 00
TagA = 0x10 = 1B
TagB = 0x00 = 1B
Null Bitmap Offset = 0x0005 = 2B
Our integer column = 0x01 = 1B
Column Count = 0x0001 = 2B
NULL Bitmap = 0x0000 = 2B (what!?)
```

Comment: Is this just educational? I'm all for trimming space where necessary, but this is probably not the 1 byte I'm going to be worried about...

Comment: This is educational. My next SQLSaturday talk is on compressin; so, I have created examples for every data type to help people understand the implications of their data type choices and to show the affect of compression on all data types.

Comment: I assumed that tinyint would be stored as 1B (it is) with 7B of overhead. I wonder what the extra byte is at the end of the record???

Comment: I see different results (though not sure if they're more in line with what you expect) when the TINYINT column is not the only column in the table. Seems like a pretty rare use case.

Comment: Certainly not a common concern of use case. I was just attempting to show each data type alone to drive home both the overhead costs involved in storage and to let beginners see what the column looks like on the page. I find it odd to have the extra byte...drives me nuts to see it there and without reason.

Comment: You are correct though. When I add an integer in the row alongside the tinyint, I get a 12B row, which is consistent with 1B (tinyint)+ 4B (int) + 7B overhead. Really makes me wonder what the darned extra byte was doing there when the tinyint was alone!

Comment: Aaron, do you know anyone on the storage team who might be willing to answer this question? Tomorrow, I'll pester Geoff Hiten to find me someone if anyone really would care to answer or can repeat my result.

Comment: I would like to add that the column count should be 0x0001 and the null bitmap mask 0x0000. Why the bitmap mask it 2B in this case...well, I have no idea

Comment: @ooutwire - The column count is `0x0100` and the offset is `0x0500` you need to reverse the bytes. Though the Null_Bitmap afterwards is just one byte `0x00` and there is still an unaccounted for `0x00` in the `DBCC PAGE` output.

Comment: I did reverse the bytes. 0x0100 is just showing the least significant byte first; so, showing it as 0X0001 is correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you compute the record using the simple size addition you indeed get 8: 4+1+2+1 (header+fixed size+null bitmap count+ null bitmap itself). But **a heap record cannot be smaller than the forwarding stub size**, which is 9 bytes, since the record must *guarantee* that it can be replaced with a forwarding stub. Hence, the record will by actually 9 bytes. A `smallint` will be 9 bytes both by means of compute and min size. Anything bigger is already bigger than the forwarding stub, so your compute size matches the record size.

Comment: The 9 bytes also applies to this definition `CREATE TABLE tbl (i TINYINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)` so is it just a general rule for all rows whether or not they are part of a heap?

Comment: The b-tree can be transformed into a heap (`alter table ... drop constraint`) and the operation is not a full rebuild (the b-tree upper pages get thrown away, the leaf pages left get unlinked and the result *is* the heap) so the reservation logic still applies.

Comment: I think this proves out what Remus has stated...http://improve.dk/archive/2011/06/07/anatomy-of-a-forwarded-record-ndash-the-forwarding-stub.aspx

Answer (score 6):

It's nice to have the ear of the author. :-) Kalen suspects this is just enforcement of some sort of minimum row length, where anything < 9 is padded to 9. Of course there are only a few cases where this is possible. You will find this phantom byte for TINYINT and BIT as well as VARCHAR(1)/CHAR(1). It won't increase beyond 9 if you move to SMALLINT or CHAR(2), but it will increase if you move to, say, CHAR(3).

So essentially you can point out the efficiencies you can gain by choosing data types wisely, but point out that there are some edge cases where the rules don't hold due to other factors at the storage layer.

**EDIT** I do hope to have more concrete information for you. Just wanted to let you know that this is what the author of the Internals book currently thinks. She's not 100% certain.

Comment: Thank you Aaron for reaching out to Kalen. I was digging through that book last night and pulling my hair out. This is kinda like the extra metadata bytes for sql_variant except here I have no way to explain the phantom byte save for hand waving and shouting "That is the way it is pal!"

Comment: Well you can couple that comment with "this is an extreme edge case, since not many tables are ever designed to try to store a single tinyint or char(1) in each row."