# Calculate row size and max row size for a table

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, information-schema

Is there any way of calculating the number of bytes occupied by the table? I know that you can get some information from `information_schema.tables` but that information is not accurate enough.

What actually required is the number of bytes according to the definition of the table for **InnoDB only** and collation could also be considered as **utf-8-general-ci**.

For example, a table `test` is as following

```
create table test   (
   col1 varchar(25),
   col2 int,
   col3 varchar(3),
   col4 char(15),
   col5 datetime    
);
```

I would require to know the total row size that can be accumulated in one row, according to the types of columns in the table.

Found a some sort of [similar solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66471/script-to-estimate-row-sizes-for-any-table) for MS SQL Server, but need its MySQL version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much of thinking and researching found one answer which really helped in achieving what  was required. It is a perl script and reference link is

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
$| = 1;

my %DataType = (
"TINYINT"=>1, "SMALLINT"=>2, "MEDIUMINT"=>3, "INT"=>4, "INTEGER"=>4, "BIGINT"=>8,
"FLOAT"=>'$M<=24?4:8', "DOUBLE"=>8,
"DECIMAL"=>'int(($M-$D)/9)*4+int(((($M-$D)%9)+1)/2)+int($D/9)*4+int((($D%9)+1)/2)',
"NUMERIC"=>'int(($M-$D)/9)*4+int(((($M-$D)%9)+1)/2)+int($D/9)*4+int((($D%9)+1)/2)',
"BIT"=>'($M+7)>>3',
"DATE"=>3, "TIME"=>3, "DATETIME"=>8, "TIMESTAMP"=>4, "YEAR"=>1,
"BINARY"=>'$M',"CHAR"=>'$M*$CL',
"VARBINARY"=>'$M+($M>255?2:1)', "VARCHAR"=>'$M*$CL+($M>255?2:1)',
"ENUM"=>'$M>255?2:1', "SET"=>'($M+7)>>3',
"TINYBLOB"=>9, "TINYTEXT"=>9,
"BLOB"=>10, "TEXT"=>10,
"MEDIUMBLOB"=>11, "MEDIUMTEXT"=>11,
"LONGBLOB"=>12, "LONGTEXT"=>12
);

my %DataTypeMin = (
"VARBINARY"=>'($M>255?2:1)', "VARCHAR"=>'($M>255?2:1)'
);

my ($D, $M, $S, $C, $L, $dt, $dp ,$bc, $CL);
my $fieldCount = 0;
my $byteCount = 0;
my $byteCountMin = 0;
my @fields = ();
my $fieldName;
my $tableName;
my $defaultDbCL = 1;
my $defaultTableCL = 1;
my %charsetMaxLen;
my %collationMaxLen;

open (CHARSETS, "mysql -B --skip-column-names information_schema -e 'select CHARACTER_SET_NAME,MAXLEN from CHARACTER_SETS;' |");
%charsetMaxLen = map ( ( /^(\w+)/ => /(\d+)$/ ), <CHARSETS>);
close CHARSETS;

open (COLLATIONS, "mysql -B --skip-column-names information_schema -e 'select COLLATION_NAME,MAXLEN from CHARACTER_SETS INNER JOIN COLLATIONS USING(CHARACTER_SET_NAME);' |");
%collationMaxLen = map ( ( /^(\w+)/ => /(\d+)$/ ), <COLLATIONS>);
close COLLATIONS;

open (TABLEINFO, "mysqldump -d --compact ".join(" ",@ARGV)." |");

while (<TABLEINFO>) {
chomp;
if ( ($S,$C) = /create database.*?`([^`]+)`.*default\scharacter\sset\s+(\w+)/i ) {
$defaultDbCL = exists $charsetMaxLen{$C} ? $charsetMaxLen{$C} : 1;
print "Database: $S".($C?" DEFAULT":"").($C?" CHARSET $C":"")." (bytes per char: $defaultDbCL)\n\n";
next;
}
if ( /^create table\s+`([^`]+)`.*/i ) {
$tableName = $1;
@fields = ();
next;
}
if ( $tableName && (($C,$L) = /^\)(?:.*?default\scharset=(\w+))?(?:.*?collate=(\w+))?/i) ) {
$defaultTableCL = exists $charsetMaxLen{$C} ? $charsetMaxLen{$C} : (exists $collationMaxLen{$L} ? $collationMaxLen{$L} : $defaultDbCL);
print "Table: $tableName".($C||$L?" DEFAULT":"").($C?" CHARSET $C":"").($L?" COLLATION $L":"")." (bytes per char: $defaultTableCL)\n";
$tableName = "";
$fieldCount = 0;
$byteCount = 0;
$byteCountMin = 0;
while ($_ = shift @fields) {
if ( ($fieldName,$dt,$dp,$M,$D,$S,$C,$L) = /\s\s`([^`]+)`\s+([a-z]+)(\((\d+)(?:,(\d+))?\)|\((.*)\))?(?:.*?character\sset\s+(\w+))?(?:.*?collate\s+(\w+))?/i ) {
$dt = uc $dt;
if (exists $DataType{$dt}) {
if (length $S) {
$M = ($S =~ s/(\'.*?\'(?!\')(?=,|$))/$1/g);
$dp = "($M : $S)"
}
$D = 0 if !$D;
$CL = exists $charsetMaxLen{$C} ? $charsetMaxLen{$C} : (exists $collationMaxLen{$L} ? $collationMaxLen{$L} : $defaultTableCL);
$bc = eval($DataType{$dt});
$byteCount += $bc;
$byteCountMin += exists $DataTypeMin{$dt} ? $DataTypeMin{$dt} : $bc;
} else {
$bc = "??";
}
$fieldName.="\t" if length($fieldName) < 8;
print "bytes:\t".$bc."\t$fieldName\t$dt$dp".($C?" $C":"").($L?" COLL $L":"")."\n";
++$fieldCount;
}
}
print "total:\t$byteCount".($byteCountMin!=$byteCount?"\tleast: $byteCountMin":"\t\t")."\tcolumns: $fieldCount\n\n";
next;
}
push @fields, $_;
}
close TABLEINFO;
```

Thanks all for great help.

Answer (score 10):

Here are my two cents using SQL and querying the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table, based on the MySQL documentation '[Data type storage requirements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html)'.

**Note**: this is not be entirely accurate, as ENUM and SET column sizes depend on the number of enumeration values, respectively set members. Here I used the "worst-case" values (2 and 8 bytes respectively), this already gives a good hint about the row size. One might parse the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_TYPE to get the number of enum values/set members for such columns and then compute the amount of bytes based on what the documentation says.

```
SELECT col_sizes.TABLE_SCHEMA, col_sizes.TABLE_NAME, SUM(col_sizes.col_size) AS EST_MAX_ROW_SIZE
FROM (
    SELECT 
        cols.TABLE_SCHEMA, 
        cols.TABLE_NAME, 
        cols.COLUMN_NAME,
        CASE cols.DATA_TYPE
            WHEN 'tinyint' THEN 1
            WHEN 'smallint' THEN 2
            WHEN 'mediumint' THEN 3
            WHEN 'int' THEN 4
            WHEN 'bigint' THEN 8
            WHEN 'float' THEN IF(cols.NUMERIC_PRECISION > 24, 8, 4)
            WHEN 'double' THEN 8
            WHEN 'decimal' THEN ((cols.NUMERIC_PRECISION - cols.NUMERIC_SCALE) DIV 9)*4  + (cols.NUMERIC_SCALE DIV 9)*4 + CEIL(MOD(cols.NUMERIC_PRECISION - cols.NUMERIC_SCALE,9)/2) + CEIL(MOD(cols.NUMERIC_SCALE,9)/2)
            WHEN 'bit' THEN (cols.NUMERIC_PRECISION + 7) DIV 8
            WHEN 'year' THEN 1
            WHEN 'date' THEN 3
            WHEN 'time' THEN 3 + CEIL(cols.DATETIME_PRECISION /2)
            WHEN 'datetime' THEN 5 + CEIL(cols.DATETIME_PRECISION /2)
            WHEN 'timestamp' THEN 4 + CEIL(cols.DATETIME_PRECISION /2)
            WHEN 'char' THEN cols.CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH
            WHEN 'binary' THEN cols.CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH
            WHEN 'varchar' THEN IF(cols.CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH > 255, 2, 1) + cols.CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH
            WHEN 'varbinary' THEN IF(cols.CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH > 255, 2, 1) + cols.CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH
            WHEN 'tinyblob' THEN 9
            WHEN 'tinytext' THEN 9
            WHEN 'blob' THEN 10
            WHEN 'text' THEN 10
            WHEN 'mediumblob' THEN 11
            WHEN 'mediumtext' THEN 11
            WHEN 'longblob' THEN 12
            WHEN 'longtext' THEN 12
            WHEN 'enum' THEN 2
            WHEN 'set' THEN 8
            ELSE 0
        END AS col_size
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS cols
) AS col_sizes
GROUP BY col_sizes.TABLE_SCHEMA, col_sizes.TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 3):

Step 1:

```
col1 varchar(25),  2 + avg_byte_len
col2 int,          4
col4 char(15),     1*15 or 3*15 or...
col5 datetime      Pre-5.6: 8; then 5

SELECT AVG(LENGTH(col1)) as avg_byte_len,
       AVG(CHAR_LENGTH(col1) as avg_num_chars FROM ...;
```

20 English characters: 2 + 1*20

20 Mid-eastern / Slavic characters: 2 + 2*20
20 Asian characters: 2 + 3*20

20 Emoji characters: 2 + 4*20 (and you need `utf8mb4`)

Step 2:  Add those up.

Step 3:  Multiply by somewhere between 2 and 3 to allow for InnoDB overhead.  I have found that that factor *usually* works.  (But not for tiny tables, and not necessarily well for partitioned tables.)

I see no reason for taking the maximum size of each column.

You can get closer than `SHOW TABLE STATUS` or the equivalent `information_schema` data:

Step 1:  `SELECT COUNT(*)` -- use this in place of `Rows`

Step 2:  Get `Data_length + Index_length + Data_free`

Step 3:  Divide.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a rough bash script to calculate row size and warn if it passes the limit based on schema:

```
#!/bin/bash
​
#
# usage: mysqldump --no-data | check_row_size.sh
#
​
#
#
# https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html#row-size-limits
#
# The maximum row size for an InnoDB table, which applies to data stored locally within a database page, is slightly less than half a page for 4KB, 8KB, 16KB, and 32KB innodb_page_size settings.
# For example, the maximum row size is slightly less than 8KB for the default 16KB InnoDB page size.
#
#
# MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'innodb_page_size';
#+------------------+-------+
#| Variable_name    | Value |
#+------------------+-------+
#| innodb_page_size | 16384 |
#+------------------+-------+
#1 row in set (0.00 sec)
#
#
# Options:
# 1. Change default innodb_page_size to 32k
# 2. Change storage engine to DYNAMIC for tables
# 3. ?
#
​
#===========================================================================================
# Functions
#===========================================================================================
RETVAL=0
​
calc_row_size() {
    local -n TABLE_FIELDS=$1
    local -n TABLE_CHARSET=$2
    local FIELD_TYPE=""
    local FIELD_SIZE=""
    local FIELD=""
    local ROW_SIZE=0
    local IFS=$'|' # To split the vars using set
    for FIELD in "${TABLE_FIELDS[@]}"  
    do  
        set $FIELD
        FIELD_NAME=$1
        FIELD_TYPE=$2
        FIELD_SIZE=$3        
        calc_field_size_in_bytes $FIELD_TYPE $FIELD_SIZE $TABLE_CHARSET
        ROW_SIZE=$((ROW_SIZE + RETVAL))
        [ $DEBUG -gt 0 ] && echo "DEBUG1: Field name: $FIELD_NAME type: $FIELD_TYPE lenght: $FIELD_SIZE size: $RETVAL bytes Row size: $ROW_SIZE"
    done  
    RETVAL=$ROW_SIZE
}
​
calc_field_size_in_bytes() {
    local TYPE=$1
    local SIZE=$2
    local CHARSET=$3

    case $FIELD_TYPE in
        varchar)
            # https://adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/12/04/about-using-utf-8-fields-in-mysql/
            # Max 3 bytes per utf-8 chat in mysql
            case $CHARSET in
                utf8)
                    RETVAL=$((SIZE * 3))  # 3 bytes per character for utf8 
                ;;
                latin1)
                    RETVAL=$((SIZE))  # 1 byte per character for latin1
                ;;
                *)
                    echo "Unknown charset ($CHARSET), please fix the script"
                    exit 1
                ;;
            esac
        ;;
        smallint|int|bigint|tinyint|varbinary)
            RETVAL=$SIZE
        ;;
        blob)
            # https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html#row-size-limits
            # BLOB and TEXT columns only contribute 9 to 12 bytes toward the row size limit because their contents are stored separately from the rest of the row.
            RETVAL=9
        ;;
        text)
            RETVAL=12
        ;;
        timestamp)
            RETVAL=4 
        ;; 
        decimal)
            # https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-numeric
            # Each multiple of nine digits requires four bytes, and the “leftover” digits require some fraction of four bytes. 
            if [[ $SIZE =~ ([0-9]+),([0-9]+) ]] 
            then
              INTEGER_PART=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
              FRACTIONAL_PART=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
​
              INTEGER_BYTES=$((INTEGER_PART / 9 * 4))
              REMAINDER=$((INTEGER_PART % 9))
              case $REMAINDER in
                  0) INTEGER_BYTES=$((INTEGER_BYTES + 0)); ;;
                  1) INTEGER_BYTES=$((INTEGER_BYTES + 1)); ;;
                  2) INTEGER_BYTES=$((INTEGER_BYTES + 1)); ;;
                  3) INTEGER_BYTES=$((INTEGER_BYTES + 2)); ;;
                  4) INTEGER_BYTES=$((INTEGER_BYTES + 2)); ;;
                  5) INTEGER_BYTES=$((INTEGER_BYTES + 3)); ;;
                  6) INTEGER_BYTES=$((INTEGER_BYTES + 3)); ;;
                  7) INTEGER_BYTES=$((INTEGER_BYTES + 4)); ;;
                  8) INTEGER_BYTES=$((INTEGER_BYTES + 4)); ;;
              esac
​
              FRACTIONAL_BYTES=$((FRACTIONAL_PART / 9 * 4))
              REMAINDER=$((FRACTIONAL_PART % 9))
              case $REMAINDER in
                  0) FRACTIONAL_BYTES=$((FRACTIONAL_BYTES + 0)); ;;
                  1) FRACTIONAL_BYTES=$((FRACTIONAL_BYTES + 1)); ;;
                  2) FRACTIONAL_BYTES=$((FRACTIONAL_BYTES + 1)); ;;
                  3) FRACTIONAL_BYTES=$((FRACTIONAL_BYTES + 2)); ;;
                  4) FRACTIONAL_BYTES=$((FRACTIONAL_BYTES + 2)); ;;
                  5) FRACTIONAL_BYTES=$((FRACTIONAL_BYTES + 3)); ;;
                  6) FRACTIONAL_BYTES=$((FRACTIONAL_BYTES + 3)); ;;
                  7) FRACTIONAL_BYTES=$((FRACTIONAL_BYTES + 4)); ;;
                  8) FRACTIONAL_BYTES=$((FRACTIONAL_BYTES + 4)); ;;
              esac
              [ $DEBUG -gt 0 ] && echo "DEBUG1: Calulation of decimal: SIZE: $SIZE INTEGER_PART:$INTEGER_PART FRACTIONAL_PART:$FRACTIONAL_PART TOTAL = INTEGER_BYTES($INTEGER_BYTES) + FRACTIONAL_BYTES($FRACTIONAL_BYTES)"
              RETVAL=$((INTEGER_BYTES + FRACTIONAL_BYTES)) 
            else
                echo "Seems like SIZE ($SIZE) for a decimal field doesn't match pattern ([0-9]+),([0-9]+). Please investigate"
                exit 1
            fi
        ;;
        *)
            echo "Found a field type that is not handled: $TYPE. Please fix before proceeding."
            exit 1
        ;;
    esac
}
​
​
#===========================================================================================
# INIT
#===========================================================================================
INSIDE_CREATE_TABLE_STATEMENT=false # True if we are within a create table statement
TABLE_NAME=''  # Current table name
ROW_SIZE=0 # Current row size being calculated
DEBUG=0
VERBOSE=0
MAX_SIZE=8126 # Default
declare -a FIELDS # List of fields from the current CREATE TABLE statement
​
#===========================================================================================
# Parameters
#===========================================================================================
OPTIND=1         # Reset in case getopts has been used previously in the shell.
​
while getopts "hvdt:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
    h)
        echo "Usage: mysqldump --no-data | ./check_row_size [-v|-d] [-t threshold]"
        exit 0
        ;;
    v) VERBOSE=1
        ;;
    d) DEBUG=2
        ;;
    t) MAX_SIZE=$OPTARG
        ;;
    esac
done
​
​
#===========================================================================================
# MAIN Loop - parses schema then calc row_size based on charset
#===========================================================================================
while IFS= read -r LINE
do
    [ $DEBUG -gt 1 ] && echo "DEBUG2: Read: $LINE"
    # Are we within a CREATE TABLE statement?
    if [ $INSIDE_CREATE_TABLE_STATEMENT == "false" ]
    then
        # Nope, is the current line a 'CREATE TABLE' statement?
        if [[ $LINE =~ ^"CREATE TABLE \`"([^\`]+) ]] 
        then
            [ $DEBUG -gt 0 ] && echo "CREATE TABLE FOUND!: $TABLE_NAME"
            TABLE_NAME=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} # What has been caught between pattern parenthesis
            INSIDE_CREATE_TABLE_STATEMENT='true'
            FIELDS=()
        fi
        continue # Ok, next line 
    fi
    # Is this a create table field definition line?
    if [[ $LINE =~ ^' '+'`'([^'`']+)'` '([a-z]+)'('([^')']+) ]]
    then
        FIELD_NAME=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        FIELD_TYPE=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        FIELD_SIZE=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
        FIELDS+=( "$FIELD_NAME|$FIELD_TYPE|$FIELD_SIZE" )
        continue
    fi
    # Have we reached the end of the CREATE TABLE statement?
    if [[ $LINE =~ ^") ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET="([^ ]+) ]] 
    then
        CHARSET=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        [ $DEBUG -gt 0 ] && echo "End of CREATE TABLE statement"
        calc_row_size FIELDS CHARSET
        ROW_SIZE=$RETVAL
        if [ $ROW_SIZE -gt $MAX_SIZE ]
        then
            echo "Table: $TABLE_NAME has a row size: $ROW_SIZE Bytes > $MAX_SIZE Bytes Charset: $CHARSET"
            # and is going to cause problem if the we upgrade to tables in ROW_FORMAT compact. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/troubleshooting-row-size-too-large-errors-with-innodb/ for more details."
        fi
        INSIDE_CREATE_TABLE_STATEMENT='false'
    fi
done
```

​

Answer (score -1):

You need to know the size in bytes of each field according to the data type ([MySQL reference here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-types.html)), then sum up these values together.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few questions of this type already, for instance this one: [How to estimate/predict data size and index size of a table in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46069/how-to-estimate-predict-data-size-and-index-size-of-a-table-in-mysql)

One difference between that question and your table is the presence of variable length strings in your's - remember to account for the maximum size that they can be.

Also remember that from version 5 onwards that `varchar(25)` is up to 25 *characters* not up to 25 *bytes* so if you are likely to see non-ASCII characters in your strings the column size could balloon up to a maximum of 100 bytes because some characters take four bytes to represent - for instance "pile of poo emoji" (which, I jest ye not, does exist - if your current browser+font support it it looks like: ) is 0xF0 0x9F 0x92 0xA9. Prior to v5 mySQL counted bytes not characters when specifying string type lengths.

*Edit Regarding Automation*

In terms of automating the process, you should be able to derive all the information needed from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables in a similar manner to the script you have found for MS SQL Server. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html for some documentation covering that.

Comment: @DavidSpillett The op is asking about max row size, information schema only provides information aobut average row size.