# Identical tables, identical columns, identical records, but why different record sizes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-internals

Identical tables, identical columns, identical records, but why different record sizes?

```
USE [test]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mybit](
    [col1] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [col2] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [col3] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [col4] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [col5] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [col6] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [col7] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [col8] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [col9] [bit] NULL
) 
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[mybit]
VALUES (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,NULL)
GO 2

DBCC IND(test, mybit, -1);
GO

DBCC TRACEON(3604);
DBCC PAGE(test, 1, '#pagenumber', 1);
```

Both records are 10 bytes in size.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mybit2](
    [col1] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [col2] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [col3] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [col4] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [col5] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [col6] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [col7] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [col8] [bit] NOT NULL,
) 
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[mybit2]
VALUES (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mybit2] ADD [col9] [bit] NULL
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[mybit2]
VALUES (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, NULL)
GO

DBCC IND(test, mybit2, -1);
GO

DBCC TRACEON(3604);
DBCC PAGE(test, 1, '#pagenumber', 1);
```

One record is 9 bytes in size and another is 10.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thomas Cleberg is correct.

The first row you insert into `bit2` shows up in DBCC page as

```
10000500 ff080000 63
```

This breaks down as follows

```
+-------+-----------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Bytes | Hex (LSB order) |  Hex   |                                Comments               |
+-------+-----------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 0     | 10              | 0x10   | TagA                                                  |
| 1     | 00              | 0x00   | TagB                                                  |
| 2-3   | 0500            | 0x0005 | Column Count offset 0x0005 = 5                        |
| 4     | ff              | 0xff   | The bit values. All are 1. 11111111 in binary = 0xff  |
| 5-6   | 0800            | 0x0008 | The column count. 0x0008 = 8. You have 8 columns.     |
| 7     | 00              | 0x00   | The Null bitmap. None are NULL.                       |    
| 8     | 63              | 0x63   | Spare                                                 |
+-------+-----------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

(If you wonder why there is a "spare" byte. This is [explained here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14854/3690). It is to allow the row to be replaced by a forwarding pointer should the need arise. The value of it is arbitrary. For me it was `0x63`. For you it looks like it was `0x00`)

After you alter the table and add a new column with a `NULL` value (or a runtime constant default value in SQL Server 2012+ enterprise edition) then this is a metadata only change. SQL Server doesn't update existing rows. It can deduce from the column count stored in the row that the value for `col9` should be `NULL` for that row. The change will be written out next time the row is updated.

Newly inserted rows *will* get written out in full though. Two extra bytes are needed because the single byte in the fixed data section is full up with values for bit columns 1-8 so an additional byte is needed for bit columns 9 to 16. Additionally the Null bitmap grows by a byte too. However there is no need to retain that "spare" byte to keep the rowsize at a minimum level so the net effect is an increase in one byte.

```
+-------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Bytes | Hex (LSB order) |  Hex   |                                      Comments                                      |
+-------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0     | 10              | 0x10   | TagA                                                                               |
| 1     | 00              | 0x00   | TagB                                                                               |
| 2-3   | 0600            | 0x0006 | Column Count offset 0x0006 =6                                                      |
| 4-5   | ff00            | 0xff00 | The bit values. An extra byte has now been added to accomodate the 9th bit column. |
| 6-7   | 0900            | 0x0009 | The column count. You now have 9 columns.                                          |
| 8-9   | 0001            | 0x0100 | The Null bitmap. The 9th column is NULL. 100000000 in binary is 0x0100             |
+-------+-----------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Great answer Martin! I always thought that NULL bitmap is minimum 2 bytes long though. Could you please clarify on how you got it 1 bytes long in your tables before I accept it as an asnwer?

Comment: @PavelNefyodov - The easiest way to see that would be to create a table with less than 8 columns but for which the row size would be above the 9 byte minimum. Then you no longer have that unused byte confusing things. Or [see Paul Randal's example here](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-record/) where it happens to use a single byte. (Byte 10 in his case)

Comment: I have no problem with an extra "spare" byte. I think your explanation on that is brilliant. I am just a bit confused with bytes 5-6 and 7 in your first table. My understanding was that [NULL bitmap is minimum 2 bytes long] [1]. [1]: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178085(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: @PavelNefyodov - Probably they are including the column count offset AKA NULL bitmap offset (depends where you are counting from) in that `Null_Bitmap` as otherwise the fixed overhead would need to be 6.

Answer (score 3):

> Identical tables, identical columns, identical records

Not entirely true. At first they were different, and row 1 was added to `[mybit2]` when they were different. Your second image, the `DBCC PAGE` output for `[mybit2]`, clearly indicates this fact.

> Why different record sizes?

Simply put: *you changed the table definition and didn't rebuild it*. Some operations can be carried out instantly (a.k.a. "online") as there is no pressing need to immediately reflect those changes on existing rows:

- Adding a NULL field
- Adding a NOT NULL, non-blob/UDT field with a default that is a runtime constant (starting in SQL Server 2012)
- Dropping columns
- Reclaiming space after adding the [SPARSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx) option (sometimes) to a NULLable field (starting in SQL Server 2008)

  [ The MSDN page for [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) has notes regarding: adding NOT NULL columns with a DEFAULT, dropping columns, and adding the `SPARSE` option. ]

In these cases, you need to rebuild the Clustered Index (or the table if it is a heap), which is when SQL Server will go through each record and make any necessary adjustments. Do the following to see it:

1. drop the `[mybit2]` table
2. run your script again to create `[mybit2]` with 8 fields, add a row, then ALTER to add the 9th field, and add a row
3. exec: `DBCC PAGE` just to make sure that record 1 is 9 bytes and record 2 is 10 bytes
4. now exec: `ALTER TABLE dbo.mybit2 REBUILD;`
5. exec: `DBCC IND(0, mybit2, -1); -- 0 = current DB` since the rebuild likely moved the contents to another page
6. exec: `DBCC PAGE` again (with the new PagePID!) and you will see that the "Record Size" for both records is now 10 bytes

Even more fun:

1. exec: `ALTER TABLE dbo.mybit2 DROP COLUMN col5;`
2. exec:

   ```
    DBCC TRACEON(3604) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
    DBCC PAGE(0, 1, {PagePID}, 3) WITH TABLERESULTS; -- 0 = current DB
    DBCC TRACEOFF(3604) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
   ```

   Both records still have a "Record Size" of 10 bytes, but what was `col5` now shows as `DROPPED`.
3. now exec: `ALTER TABLE dbo.mybit2 REBUILD;`
4. exec: `DBCC IND(0, mybit2, -1); -- 0 = current DB` since the rebuild likely moved the contents to another page
5. exec:

   ```
    DBCC TRACEON(3604) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
    DBCC PAGE(0, 1, {newPagePID}, 3) WITH TABLERESULTS; -- 0 = current DB
    DBCC TRACEOFF(3604) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
   ```

   Both records now have a "Record Size" of 9 bytes, and no more placeholder for `col5` that shows as `DROPPED` in the `Field` column

Answer (score 2):

Your second table has 8 columns, the first has 9. As the data type is "Bit", that accounts for exactly the difference.

Comment: How exactly did you calculate the difference?

Comment: 8Bit + 1Bit (definition) For 8 Columns (of bit type), 9 Bit + 1Bit for 9.

Comment: That is not correct. In case of nine columns size would be 10 bytes = row overhead (4 bytes)+ NULL bitmap (4 bytes) + size of nine bit columns(2 bytes).

Comment: Apologies, you are correct [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx) though the addition of the 9th bit column to go from 1->2 byte storage still accounts for the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something, but you realize that start off with 8 columns, do an insert then **alter the table and add a 9th column** and then do another insert.  Of course the size is going to be different when the first insert was into 8 columns and the second was into 9 columns.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "of course the size is going to be different"?

Comment: You are going from 8 columns to 9 columns. 8 is not equal to 9, hence a size difference. Are you thinking it would not grow because you put a NULL in the last column? If so, it takes space even to store NULL value. A bit is a fixed-length data type so it allocates the space even when there is no value in anticipation of the future value.  Just like a char[10] column is always 10 bytes long whether you put in 1 character, 10, or even a NULL.

Comment: It seems like it is because column information is not stored in a record on new expanded table.