# How does a integer data record store in SQL Server page

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dbcc, row, data-pages

I have seen the 8KB (8192 = 96 Header + 36 Row Offset + 8060 Free space) page architecture in SQL Server. When it comes to storing a data record in Page i am confused.

In Below table i have create Integer for column ID it should take 4 Bytes but each record size/length is showing in DBCC PAGE Command 11 Bytes.

I have created a simple table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE PAGETEST
(
    ID int primary key
)
GO
INSERT INTO PAGETEST values (200)
```

Q 1). Why a simple integer data is taking 4 actual bytes of data + 7 Bytes extra = 11 Bytes.
Q 2). Can anybody explain how does a record store in a page.

Kindly find the images below:

[image]

Comment: Read this please :https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-record/ ;
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/practicalsqldba/2012/08/22/sql-serverunderstanding-the-data-record-structure/

Comment: I believe  size 11 is because :      1 byte (for status bits 1 )+
     1 byte (for status bits 2 )+
     2 bytes (used to store the size of fixed length columns)+
     4 bytes (of fixed length column  ID )+
     2 bytes (used to store total number of columns)+
     1 byte  (for null bitmap)

Comment: Hello Sabin, Can you please explain in breif what are these status bits and null bitmap and why it is storing 2 bytes for total columns and how.

Comment: Try to read , from Paul Randal, https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-record/  His article is more precise and he is well inform

Answer (score 1):

One important thing to keep in mind is that rowstore tables have a minimum row size of 9 bytes. You can see some details about that in the answer and comments [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14774/sql-server-storage-of-tinyint/14854#14854). If you're going to be creating sample data and digging around in pages I recommend creating at least a few columns to make what you're looking at more clear. Otherwise you can run into a case where a table with a single `TINYINT` column appears to take up as much space as a table with a single `SMALLINT`, which doesn't make sense at first.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.X_TINYINT (ID SMALLINT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE dbo.X_SMALLINT (ID SMALLINT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO dbo.X_TINYINT WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT TOP (100000) 0
FROM master..spt_values t1
CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

INSERT INTO dbo.X_SMALLINT WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT * FROM dbo.X_TINYINT;

sp_spaceused 'X_TINYINT'; -- 1096 KB reserved

sp_spaceused 'X_SMALLINT'; -- 1096 KB reserved
```

Answer (score 0):

This is explained better in this article as mentioned by @sabin bio.
https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-record/

In your page dump if you look at hex value of c8 it turns out to be 200 in decimal. That is the data you inserted.
c8000000 takes 4 bytes and that is fixed length data.
4 (1000800) and 3 (01000) bytes before and after fixed length data are explained in Paul's blog post.